KubeFLow (KFP) - writing log files to the Google cloud storage
I have a pipeline running using kfp (kubeflow) on GCP. I can add logs to the terminal, but I am having problems writing logs to a file and save it in a .path (Cloud Storage). Here is my running code which prints logs at terminal.
from kfp.dsl import Artifact, Dataset, Input, Metrics, Model, Output, component, Markdown

@component(
    base_image="europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ml-repo/bigquery",
)
def read_data_from_big_query_component(
    raw_dataset: Output[Dataset],
):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    import logging
    
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    logger.info("LOG - INFO 1: Starting the BigQuery data reading process.")

    # Connect to BigQuery
    client = bigquery.Client(project="my project ID goes here")
    
    logger.info("LOG - INFO 2: Connected to the BigQuery client.")

    query = f"""      
      SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
      WHERE customer_name = "MY CUSTOMER NAME" and DATETIME >= "DATE"
      ORDER BY DATETIME;
      """
    
    logger.info("LOG - INFO 3: Query prepared.")

    logger.info("LOG - INFO 4: Fetched data successfully.")

    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    query_job = client.query(query=query, job_config=job_config)
    df = query_job.result().to_dataframe()

    logger.info(f"LOG - INFO 5: Number of rows fetched: {len(df)}")

    logger.info(f"LOG - INFO 6: Data preview:\n{df.head()}")
    
    logger.info("LOG - INFO 7: Data converted to dataframe.")
    
    if df.empty:
        logger.warning("LOG - WARNING 1: The fetched data from BigQuery is empty.")

    # print(df.head())
    df.to_csv(raw_dataset.path, index=False)
    
    logger.info(f'LOG - INFO 8: Data saved to a CSV file as {raw_dataset}.')
    logger.info("LOG - INFO 9: BigQuery data reading process completed.")`


I have tried things like this, with no luck:
logname = 'test.log'
logfile = os.path.join(os.pardir, logname)

logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)

